# Submission form with input duplicates

Tags: php, html

I have a button that duplicates two inputs with their own id (i++ and r++ from original). When I submit the form and run:

```
foreach ($_POST as $id => $value) {
    echo $value;            
}
```

process.php page doesn't recognise the new inputs $id or $value.

The duplication code is the following:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate
var i = 0;
var r = 0;
var items = document.getElementById('items');
var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad');
function duplicate() {
 var cloneitems = items.cloneNode(false); // "deep" clone
 cloneitems.id = "items" + ++r; // there can only be one element with an ID
 items.parentNode.appendChild(cloneitems);
 var cloneCantidad = cantidad.cloneNode(false); // "deep" clone
 cloneCantidad.id = "cantidad" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
 cantidad.parentNode.appendChild(cloneCantidad);
}
```

My html:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <h4 class="input-margin">Items<button type="button" id="button" onclick="duplicate()" class="btn btn-primary margin-left input-margin">+</button></h4>
  <div>
   <div class="input-margin">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     // First duplicated input
     <select class="input-margin form-control" id="items" placeholder="Nombre" name="item" data-style="btn-primary">
      <option></option>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($itemResults)) :  ?>
      <option><?php echo $row['item']; ?></option>   
      <?php endwhile; ?>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
     // Second duplicated input
     <input type="number" class="input-margin form-control txtboxToFilter" id="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" name="cantidad" min="1">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 submit-button">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="ingreso">Ingresar</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

The user must have the possibility to use as many duplications as they want. Each of them will have different inputs, thats why I need unique ids to make changes in mysql.

Why is the new id not being showed or recognise, and is there any better way to get all the values from the duplicated inputs?

Comment: Since you haven't shown the html that you're fiddling with, we can't help. PHP couldn't care less what the JS code is - it only sees what the browers turns your HTML into when the form is submitted.

Comment: I would suggest using jquery first, it's way easier to work with. using jquery, i would use the serializeArrays function to get the value of your form and then send it to your server using an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form fields are posted with their names, not their ID. So each of the appended input will overwrite the others. Differentiate the name and you will get each. Or you can give these input an array as name: 
`name="cantitad[]"` 
and you will get one array with all the values.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for your help! After giving the array as name, how can I those values in php?

Comment: just use a foreach on each array. If you have more than one array you can also use them in sync checking the keys